# Add class when done "checked" in the input section

Tags: jquery

need to add a class to the container that has no input selected
this is my attempt
jquery:

```
$('.section .container-items input:checked').each( function(){
     $('.section .container-items').addClass('red');
});
```

I need this result
[image]

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5KNaM/)

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Need to add a class to the container that has no input selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use this:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function() {
    var container = $(this).parent().parent();
    $(".container-items", container).each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });
    $(this).parent().removeClass("red");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5KNaM/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`.change()`**](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$('.section .container-items input').change( function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('red').siblings().addClass('red');
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UDZaN/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dJgKE/)</kbd>

```
var chck = $('.section .container-items input');//cache selector
chck.change(function () { //change event
    chck.filter(':not(:checked)').parent().addClass('red'); //add red to class red to parent if not checked
    chck.filter(':checked').parent().removeClass('red'); //checked elements remove red class
}).change(); //trigger change event
```